# ts check compare instance of this

Tags: typescript

is typescript can check a concret instance with `this` ?

Example let say we have a method to add  childs instances, but we dont want allow to pass
a `self` instance as parameter to the method !?

Typescript can do it ?

```
type AB = A | B;
export class A {
    a: string;
}
export class B {
    b: string;

    /** we are ok to pass new instance but never the self instance */
    addChild<T extends AB>(token: T extends this ? never : T) {
        return this;
    }
}

const a = new A();
const b = new B();
const bb = new B();

b.addChild(a); // should ok
b.addChild(b); // should error
b.addChild(bb); // should ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=20&ssc=31&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAggQlAvLKAfKcDcBYAUBADzAHsAnYKAYwBsBDAZ3pQG88BIWgLinuFIEsAdgHNEAcjE5cAXzyES5KnUYYorXGwBG3XgJHjJedgHoAVKagB3aLVLRiAayjBiUMAyaCIlqEN61BSmhNAFcKQWJwgDcIUmcAC2h6CGoAM19Bf0DoU2N2WgATAoBheP5qAoAeABUoQmAIQQKmeAA%20AAoXB0buWvrG5oT%20JgB%20KC8YuN6ASjV2NjtgENJBIfopNlkZI1xKYkyKWiRx71h26ak9g6hNY68fOHPL-d4b2%20R7jCedzQA6QpKZQq7VoFygxmMgF4NwBH%20zx4sQQhUoI48H8AaVygV2powRDIYAWXbhCKRsVIZFR-yKGOBmhxmHBUNh9HhiIKyIcQA)

Answer (score 2):

Typescript only deals with typing and all instances will have the same type, so this is probably not possible. (At least without passing some data that can serve as a key to the constructor)

Comment: oki thanks for the info